# scala slick postgresql create table schema

Tags: scala, slick

I am new in slick , please view this simple code :

```
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver.api._
import slick.lifted.{ProvenShape, Tag}

case class Person(id: Int, name: String)

class Persons(tag: Tag) extends Table[Person](tag, "persons") {

  val id: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  val name: Rep[String] = column[String]("name")

  override def * : ProvenShape[Person] = (id, name) <> (Person.tupled, Person.unapply)
}

object MainRunner extends App {

  val dbUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://172.17.0.2/slick-test";
  val dbUsername = "username"
  val dbPassword = "password"
  val dbDriver = "org.postgresql.Driver"

  val db = Database.forURL(url = dbUrl, driver = dbDriver, user = dbUsername, password = dbPassword)

  val persons = TableQuery[Persons]
  val queries = DBIO.seq(
    persons.schema.create
  )
  val setup = db.run(queries)
  println(setup)
}
```

are you think this code has problem ?
this code compile and run without any problem (error or exceptions)
but can not create table schema !
What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not about the session (no such thing in Slick 3.x). The problem that you have is that you don't wait till operation finishes (application finish before schema is created; that is - before `Future` executes).

Change these lines:

```
val setup = db.run(queries)
println(setup)
```

to (notice new imports):

```
import import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationLong
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
...
...
val setup = db.run(queries).foreach(_ => println("Done, schema created!))
Await.result(setup, 5L.seconds)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are starting with play+slick maybe this project can help you:

- https://github.com/pedrorijo91/play-slick3-steps
- and the tutorial http://pedrorijo.com/blog/play-slick/

Comment: No , This is only static application for test and learn slick orm .